# WooCommerce change product price and subtotal after checkout based on payment method

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two custom payment methods. I want to change the currency, product price, subtotal, shipping fee based on the payment method selected. I am using the filter `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` and successfully changed order total and shipping amount along with the currency.

Here is the code that I used to change the currency and total:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_total_after_checkout', 999, 1 );
function change_total_after_checkout($order) {
    $euro_rate = 1.15;
    $usd_rate = 1.24;

    $shipping_total = ($order->get_payment_method()==='eurosaccount') ?  ceil($order->get_shipping_total() * $euro_rate) : ceil($order->get_shipping_total() * $usd_rate);

    $total = ($order->get_payment_method()==='eurosaccount') ?  ceil($order->get_total() * $euro_rate) : ceil($order->get_total() * $usd_rate);

    if($order->get_payment_method()==='eurosaccount'){
        $order->set_currency('EUR');
        $order->set_shipping_total($shipping_total);
        $order->set_total($total);
    }elseif($order->get_payment_method()==='usaccount'){
        $order->set_currency('USD');
        $order->set_shipping_total($shipping_total);
        $order->set_total($total);
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to change the product price and subtotal. These changes need to be reflected in order emails too.

Comment: To change the product price and item subtotal you can use [woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#457) hook…